# Showing Alert of update successful but not able to click alert, and database not updated

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I click on update, a page is only getting refreshed, values are not updated. I have 4 tables in database, namely -> stud,country_master_academic,master_state, master_city. In a console, values are not showing when I click on update button.

my update.php page

```
 <div class="container" style="width:700px;height:1100px;margin-top:10%;box-shadow:4px 3px 3px 3px grey;margin-left:25%;background-color:#eaf2fa;padding:3%;">

                <h4 style="font-weight:bold;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Update Student</h4>


                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="photo"></label>
                    <?php
                $img = "images/".trim($vrow["photo"]);
                echo '<img src='.$img.' id="resultedPhoto" class="image" style="margin-left:75%;margin-top:2%;width:120px;height:120px;border:2px solid #bbbbbb;border-radius:10px;">';
                ?><br/>
                    <input type="file" name="upphoto" id="upphoto" style="margin-left:70%;" required />
                </div>

                <form class="form-horizontal" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="no"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span><b> Student No: </b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="upno" id="upno" disabled value="<?php echo $vrow['stud_no'];?>" required />
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b> Student Name: </b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="upname" id="upname" value="<?php echo $vrow['stud_name'];?>" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}" title="Name should only contain letters and atleast 3 letters"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="no"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span><b> Mobile No: </b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $vrow['mobile']; ?>" name="upmob_no" required id="upmob_no" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Mobile number should be of 10 digits"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="dob"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span><b> Birth Date: </b></label>
                    <input type="date" required class="form-control" value="<?php echo $vrow['dob'];?>"  name="updob" id="updob" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> Address: </b></label>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="33" class="form-control" name="upadd" id="upadd" required><?php echo $vrow['address'];?></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gen"><b> Gender: </b></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="M"<?php echo ($vrow['gender']=='M')?'checked':' ' ?> required="required">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale"  value="F"<?php echo ($vrow['gender']=='F')?'checked':' ' ?> required="required">Female
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cntry"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> Country: </b></label>
                <select required name="upcountry" id="upcountry" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    $country="SELECT * from country_master_academic";
                    $res= $conn->query($country);
                    if($res->num_rows>0){
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){        
                        if($row["country_name"]==$vcountry or $vrow['country'] == $row["country_code"] )
                        {   
                                echo '<option value='.$row["country_code"].' selected>'.$row["country_name"].'</option>';
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<option value='.$row["country_code"].'>'.$row["country_name"].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="state"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> State: </b></label>
                <select required name="upstate" id="upstate" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    $state="SELECT * from master_state";
                    $res= $conn->query($state);
                    if($res->num_rows>0){
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){        
                        if($row["state_name"]==$vstate or $vrow['state'] == $row["state_code"] )
                        {   
                                echo '<option value='.$row["state_code"].' selected>'.$row["state_name"].'</option>';
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<option value='.$row["state_code"].'>'.$row["state_name"].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> City: </b></label>
                <select required name="upcity" id="upcity" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    $city="SELECT * from master_city";
                    $res= $conn->query($city);
                    if($res->num_rows>0){
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){        
                        if($row["city_name"]==$vcity or $vrow['city'] == $row["city_code"] )
                        {   
                                echo '<option value='.$row["city_code"].' selected>'.$row["city_name"].'</option>';
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<option value='.$row["city_code"].'>'.$row["city_name"].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="update" id="update" style="font-weight:bold;" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
                </form>

</div>
```

upresult.php page

```
    <?php
    include("connection.php");

$no=trim($_POST['upno']);
$name=trim($_POST['upname']);
$mob=trim($_POST['upmob_no']);
$dob=trim($_POST['updob']);
$add=trim($_POST['upadd']);
$photo=trim($_FILES['upphoto']['name']);
$gen=trim($_POST['gender']);
$cn=trim($_POST['upcountry']);
$st=trim($_POST['upstate']);
$ct=trim($_POST['upcity']);

$qry="update stud set stud_name='".$name."',mobile='".$mob."',dob='".$dob."',address='".$add."',gender='".$gen."',country='".$cn."',state='".$st."',city='".$ct."' where stud_no='".$no."'";
$data=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
if($data)
{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Updated Successfully")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Cannot update record")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

?>

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
              $.ajax({

                 url:"upresult.php",
                 type:"POST",
                 data:{formData:formData},
                 async:true,
                 success:function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                },
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false
            });
         });
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi please add event.preventdefault() function { inside jquery click function }

Comment: is the form submitting?

Comment: @Arun Did, but its not working

Comment: @BrindhaBaskaran No, its not able to submit

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same name

```
 data:{stud_no:stud_no},  //here change the name of vbl or  value
data:{
formData:formData, //here change the name of vbl or  value
stud_no:stud_no, //here change the name of vbl or  value
}
```

Comment: @BrindhaBhaskaran  Like this?       data:{fd:formData,
                            sno:stud_no,
                            },   now this error is coming-> TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.[Learn More] home.php:103:33